# Why does my OpenGL Version String not correspond with my core profile version string?

Tags: games, intel-graphics, opengl

I am attempting to run some Unity3D games, which require "OpenGL core profile 3.2 or later for OpenGL Core renderer" (according to the games' own output).

As far as I know, I *have* OpenGL 3.3. However, my `glxinfo` output is very, very confusing:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So, I have "Core profile version" 3.3 (greater than is required by Unity3D) but my "version" is 3.1? Why is this, and what can I do about it?

I have a Intel Core i5-3320M, and am using Mesa 18.2 with the i915 driver.

Answer (score 2):

The *core profile* version is what version of GL you can use on your card with your drivers. This is what really matters, usually.

The *OpenGL version string* you can just ignore. It's the compat profile version.

However, the specific issue you are having, seems to be that your system is actually using the *llvmpipe* renderer, rather than the hardware acceleration for your actual GPU. The *vendor string* value should be something like *Intel Open Source Technology Center* with the *renderer string* something like *Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile*. You may need to make sure you have the `intel-microcode` package installed.

Comment: But then why do games that require 3.2 fail on my system, when I have 3.3?

Comment: But I'm not running under a VM! I have Xubuntu 18.04 installed on a T430s.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that the intel driver is not actually being used here, perhaps due to lack of microcode or such.

Comment: OK, I installed `intel-microcode` but, after rebooting, my system is still using `llvmpipe`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to a chain of bugs in the Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade process.

[Bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1733136), [Bug 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libglvnd/+bug/1752901), and [Bug 3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libglvnd/+bug/1751414) caused any system with `libegl` to fall back to `llvmpipe` - software rendering.

`libegl`, in turn, was incorrectly installed on systems that didn't need it, due to `libnvidia-gl-390` depending on it.

`libnvidia-gl-390` was incorrectly required on many systems. Uninstalling it fixes this issue.